# Conectar live editing

Tags: sql, android, genexus, net

Estoy generando una aplicación SD y estoy tratando de conectar el emulador con live editing, pero tengo el error de que por la dirección IP no puede acceder, pero sí puede acceder por localhost.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna maera de cambiar ese Endpoints por localhost?

También estoy ejecutando el comando netstat -at y veo que el puerto está escuchando, pero igual no se puede conectar, qué puede ser?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Comment: Como estas? fijate en este documento donde te guia para hacer troubleshooting:  https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31632,Live%20Editing%20-%20under%20the%20hood